# Error using the fancyvrb LaTeX environment

Tags: latex

Hi I'm trying to fancyvrb environment.  I'm using a fully upgraded Ubuntu 9.04.

If I issue a simple Verbatim environment, for example:

```
\begin{Verbatim}
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
```

it works.  However, if I try to pass in a parameter, for example, setting the font size:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=8]
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
```

This is ignored.  If I try to set the color:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red}]
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
```

I get the following error:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``latex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(./test.tex (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.6, with DG/SPQR fixes <1998/07/17> (tvz)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
No file fancyvrb.cfg.
) (./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\FancyVerbFormatCom ->\color 
                             {red}\relax 
l.20 \begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red}]

[1] (./test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 644 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Sep  7 15:19:05
```

I'm starting my way with LaTeX, and I'm not sure if I'm misusing it, or if I have something installed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts to your problem:

1. The `fontsize` option only accepts LaTeX font sizes such as `\small` and `\large`
2. As mentioned by others, you need to load the color package (or the xcolor package) to get colours to work.

Here's an example that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red}]
  foobar
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Colors are provided by the color package.  Try adding `\usepackage{color}`